# Python and MySQL STR_TO_DATE

Tags: python, mysql

When I execute the code (see below) I got the next error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/test/python/main.py", line 18, in <module>
  calls = tel.getCallRecordings(member['id'], member['start_date'])
File "/home/test/python/teldb.py", line 49, in getCallRecordings
  'start_date': str(start_date),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.5-freebsd-8.1-RELEASE-amd64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
TypeError: int argument required
```

The code I use is the next:

```
def getCallRecordings(self, member_id, start_date):       
    self.cursor.execute("""
    SELECT var10 as filename,
           var9 as duration
    FROM csv_data c
    LEFT JOIN transcriptions t ON
        c.id=t.call_id
    WHERE member_id=%(member_id)s AND
          var10 IS NOT NULL AND
          var9>%(min_duration)d AND
          dialed_date>STR_TO_DATE(%(start_date)s, '%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%i:%%s') AND
          t.call_id IS NULL
    ORDER BY dialed_date DESC
    """, {
        'member_id': member_id,
        'min_duration': MIN_DURATION,
        'start_date': str(start_date),
        })
    logging.debug("Executed query: %s" % self.cursor._executed)
    return self.cursor.fetchone()
```

Why I got this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show what `MIN_DURATION` is, but you use `%(min_duration)d`, so it is required to be an int.  Do you have it defined as a string or a float instead?

You don't need to use %d in a SQL query like this, the DB adapter understands the types you pass it, and will properly insert them into the query.  Make `MIN_DURATION` an integer (perhaps with `int(MIN_DURATION)` in the code you have), and it will work.

BTW: the stack trace focuses you on the `str(start_date)`, but only because that's the last source line in the executable statement that had the error, so it's misleading.

Comment: MIN_DURATION is taken from the config. MIN_DURATION = 1

Comment: still not worting even with int(MIN_DURATIN).. by the way the type() of it is int as same as for member_id

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue while constructing the sql query strings involving str_to_date function. I have used .format() operator on python strings to parametrize the SQL queries.  Here is an example query that would work just fine:

```
# Takes an input date and returns the manager's name during that period
input_string='"' + "{input_data}".format(input_data=input_data) + '"' 

sql_query='''select CONCAT(e.last_name, ",", e.first_name),STR_TO_DATE(from_date,'%Y-%m-%d'),STR_TO_DATE(to_date,'%Y-%m-%d') from dept_manager dm inner join employees e on e.emp_no=dm.emp_no where STR_TO_DATE({input_string},'%Y-%m-%d')>STR_TO_DATE(from_date,'%Y-%m-%d') and STR_TO_DATE({input_string},'%Y-%m-%d')<STR_TO_DATE(to_date,'%Y-%m-%d');'''.format(input_string=input_string)
```